# How to pass in props to snapshot test React native typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-test-renderer

i am very new to testing and im trying to create a simple snapshot test for a presentational component that accepts props. Am I suppose to 'mock' some props? Also  I am *not* using `ts-jest` as im not sure if i should.

`NutritionValue.tsx`

```
interface Item {
    title: string,
    valueConsumed: number, 
    valueRequired: number,
}

export const NutritionValue = (props: Item): JSX.Element => {
    const { title, valueConsumed, valueRequired } = props
    let label:string = ''
    switch (title) {
        case 'Calories':
            label = 'cal'
            break
        default:
            label = 'g'
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.macrocontainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}> {title} </Text>
            <Progress.Bar progress={valueConsumed/valueRequired} width={75} height={2} color="#5F8D4E" />
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}> {valueConsumed} / {valueRequired} {label} </Text>
        </View>
    )

}
//const styles = StyleSheet.create ({...})
```

`NutritionValue.test.tsx`

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { NutritionValue } from '../NutritionValue'


test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<NutritionValue  />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Comment: Simply pass them like this `const tree = renderer.create(<NutritionValue title="Calories" valueConsumed={0} valueRequired={0}  />).toJSON();` but imho only having snapshot tests is not enough. In case if you change the component and snapshot test will fail, most people just blindly update it without looking into the reason :D I would suggest you adding couple of cases with assert check for your label that gets determined by title property.

Comment: thank you! for the switch statement, should i separate that into its own function?/ or can you provide an example of the assert check?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-test-renderer` myself, but I'm sure google would help you with that. I'd personally use `react-testing-library` or `enzyme` as tests utils, I never even knew there are some built-in test utils in react :D